# How to remove the class after clicking three div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 9 div . I will add the "active" class when i click each div. I need to remove that "active" class when i click any of the div as fourth

```
 <section class="square_box tctgrid" id="question1">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div class="empty"><input type="radio" value="1" class="answer_value"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
```

```
    <script>
$( ".square_box div" ).click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass( "empty")) {
        var ans = $(this).find('.answer_value').val();
        $(this).addClass( "active");
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass( "active").addClass('error_div');;
    }
});
</script>
```

The above code is my script. I don't know how to remove the class.Please help me on this.

Comment: You need to remove the class `active` from all the divs if the 4th one is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").each(function() {
     $(this).data('count', 0);
  }
  $("div").click(function() {
    $(this).data('count', ($(this).data('count') +1));
    if($(this).data('count') == 4) {
        $("div").removeClass("active");
        $(this).data('count', 0);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If undertstood you right, this should solve your request.

```
$( ".square_box div" ).click(function() {
    $(".square_box div .active").removeClass("active");
    //handle the rest of you methods
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
    $("div").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  cursor:pointer
}
.active{
  font-weight:bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
   <div>ONE</div>
   <div>TWO</div>
   <div>THREE</div>
   <div>FOUR</div>
   <div>FIVE</div>
   <div>SIX</div>
   <div>SEVEN</div>
   <div>EIGHT</div>
```

Comment: I need to remove the class when i click the div as fourth time.